# Redirecting webhook with nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, proxypass, redirection

I am changing the domain name of my app from old.com to new.com

My app is connected to external APIs that send data through webhooks, and I would like to redirect the webhooks sent to the old url, so that they hit the new url and get processed.

I have a tried a plain rewrite

```
server {
  server_name old.com;
  listen 443 ssl;
  rewrite ^       https://new.com$request_uri;
```

I can see this triggers a 302 redirection, but that doesn't seem to do the trick..

I tried with a proxy_pass

```
server {
  server_name old.com;
  listen 443 ssl;

  location /webHook {
    proxy_pass https://new.com/webHook;
  }

  rewrite ^       https://new.com$request_uri;
```

Same result.. I can see a 302 redirect in the logs, but the webhook never seem to hit the new URL and doesn't get processed..

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rewrite` directives in the `server` block, which are not inside a `location` block are executed first (cf. [ng_http_rewrite_module documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#summary)).

So delete or comment the `rewrite` directive and the `proxy_pass` directive will get executed.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that did the trick - had to wrap the `rewrite` in a `location` block with a regexp that excluded my `/webHook` prefix and it works like a charm!

Comment: You just need to wrap it in `location /`, since prefix locations are selected based on the longest matching prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Since the webhooks are not going to get a redirect (and thus, the only way for them to absorb your new app's domain is by your manual changes), why miss a trivial solution?

Simply add `old.com` under `server` where you have `new.com`:

```
server_name new.com old.com;
```

Comment: I like the suggestion but would this not create SSL certificates issues, as the certificate registered in nginx conf file will be issued for new.com, and not for old.com?

Comment: That would be the downside, although if you have control of certificate issuance (e.g. `certbot`), you can generate a combined certificate that will be valid for both domains.